# DOMDocument xpath query image extention doesnt equal to specific ext?

Tags: dom, xpath, domdocument

getting all images aprt from png extension?

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $htmlget);
       $nodelist = $xpath->query("//img[!ends-with(@src, "png")]");
```

i know this doesnt work,  i want to be able to skip images which are png's

Comment: i think contains("src)  but does !contain work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT in xpath is a function, not an operator. Try:

```
//img[not(ends-with(@src, 'png'))]
```

Also note I have changed from double-quotes `""` to single quotes `''` as the xpath string itself is delimited by `""`.